# Trying to parse json source with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am trying to parse json source with javascript.

I have this json source:

```
var exam = '{
    status : 'connected',
    authResponse: {
    accessToken: 'it is accessToken',
    expiresIn:'2014-06-19',
    signedRequest:'it is signedRequest',
    userID:'mp172'
    }
}';
```

To parse, I use `JSON.parse(exam);`

After this source, it is not working. I want to parse this source with javascript.

Comment: While JSON and javascript object literal syntax look similar they're not the same. For example you cannot have functions in JSON, you must quote strings with `"` etc. See JSON.org for the specification of the JSON format.

Comment: ate you sure you are getting that response as a JSON source @user3750753

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your json source is not valid.
According to JSON.org, member should be quote by "

Change exam to `{"status":"connected","authResponse":{"accessToken":"it is accessToken","expiresIn":"2014-06-19","signedRequest":"it is signedRequest","userID":"mp172"}}`

Comment: Thank you answering my question, actually it is provided from facebook. i can't edit this source. and i am testing facebook development now. i know the syntax... please help me.

Comment: So the source returned by facebook is not for JSON parser, but javascript.

Try `eval('return ' + exam);`

Comment: Sorry for my eval is wrong.
Use `eval("var exam={status:'connected',authResponse:{accessToken:'it is accessToken',expiresIn:'2014-06-19',signedRequest:'it is signedRequest',userID:'mp172'}}")`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```
var exam = {status : 'connected', authResponse: { accessToken: 'it is accessToken', expiresIn:'2014-06-19', signedRequest:'it is signedRequest', userID:'mp172' }};
// stringify the response first
stringify = JSON.stringify(exam);
// stringified result
console.log(stringify);
// parse the json
final = JSON.parse(stringify);
// parsed final result
console.log(final);
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caJ2K/2/) example

Comment: why do you need to stringify it since it was already a string to start with?

Comment: @Farax looks like he is getting a javascript object as response. since its not a valid json, thats why I stringify first.

Comment: stringify would not make it a valid JSON object

Comment: @Farax stringify will add double quotes to make it valid JSON.  you can try on jsfiddle I gave above.

Comment: The jsFiddle example doesn't match with the code you have in your answer.

Comment: @FelixKling Now it does :)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid , it should look something like this ,

```
{
    "status": "connected",
    "authResponse": {
        "accessToken": "itisaccessToken",
        "expiresIn": "2014-06-19",
        "signedRequest": "itissignedRequest",
        "userID": "mp172"
    }
}
```

JSONLint show following error ,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Proper" json data has both the property name and string values in double quotes.  Browser parsers are very lenient though and the reason I think yours is failing is because it isn't a valid string.  When you open the string with `'`, the string ends on the next `'` it finds, so it should be choking when it tries to make sense of `connected',` after finding the string `'{ status : '`.  If you wrapped your JSON in single double quotes (since it uses single quotes for values) that would probably work, but comphilip is right.

Answer (score 0):

If you intended it to be a string to start with, make sure it is in one line. Otherwise, use (+) to append the string and then use JSON.parse to parse it to an object.

```
  var exam = '{"status" : "connected","authResponse": {"accessToken": "it is accessToken","expiresIn":"2014-06-19","signedRequest":"it is signedRequest","userID":"mp172"}}'


  var obj = JSON.parse(exam);
```

[image: Chrome developer tool]